# How can I test this async piece of code in Flutter using Mockito?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I am trying to write some test for an app, but I can't test values stored in a provider. I am relatively new to testing, so there might be something that I am doing wrong, but anyway. What I want to test is to verify is two values are not the same, which should be the expected behavior, but I just can't make it pass.
This is the code that I want to test:

```
class RSAKeysProvider {
    KeyPair? _keyPair;

    KeyPair? get keyPair => _keyPair;
    set setKeyPair(KeyPair keyPair) => _keyPair = keyPair;

    Future<void> generate(String bits) async {
        var keyPair = await RSA.generate(int.parse(bits));
        _keyPair = keyPair;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

I need to first call the generate() function, which will set the keyPair to actual values, and then check if keyPair.publicKey is different than keyPair.privateKey, but it gives me an error when I try to call generate() with await inside a test.

This is what I have for now, but it doesn't work. The test breaks when it cames to the line "await rsaKeys.generate('2048'). What can I do to make it work? I know the condition is not checking if both are different, but it is just a placeholder, I can't make the code arrive there!

```
test('Public and private key should be different', () async {
      final MockRSAKeysProvider rsaKeys = MockRSAKeysProvider();

      when(rsaKeys.generate(any)).thenAnswer((value) async {
        KeyPair keyPair = await RSA.generate(2048);
        rsaKeys.setKeyPair = keyPair;
      });

      await rsaKeys.generate('2048');

      expect(rsaKeys.keyPair?.privateKey, isNotNull);
      expect(rsaKeys.keyPair?.publicKey, isNotNull);
    });
```

When it arrives at "await rsaKeys.generate('2048'), it gives me this error:

```
Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'librsa_bridge.dylib': dlopen(librsa_bridge.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibrsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.7.3/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/./librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.7.3/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/../../../librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.7.3/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/Frameworks/librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.7.3/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/./librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.7.3/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/../../../librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.7.3/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/Frameworks/librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/librsa_bridge.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
  dart:ffi                                     new DynamicLibrary.open
  package:fast_rsa/bridge/binding.dart 117:33  Binding.openLib
  package:fast_rsa/bridge/binding.dart 26:16   new Binding._internal
  package:fast_rsa/bridge/binding.dart 17:45   Binding._singleton
  package:fast_rsa/bridge/binding.dart         Binding._singleton
  package:fast_rsa/bridge/binding.dart 22:12   new Binding
  package:fast_rsa/fast_rsa.dart 40:32         RSA.bindingEnabled
  package:fast_rsa/fast_rsa.dart               RSA.bindingEnabled
  package:fast_rsa/fast_rsa.dart 43:9          RSA._call
  package:fast_rsa/fast_rsa.dart 79:22         RSA._keyPairResponse
  package:fast_rsa/fast_rsa.dart 437:18        RSA.generate
  test/rsa_keys.test.dart 32:37                main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
  package:mockito/src/mock.dart 185:45         Mock.noSuchMethod
  test/rsa_keys.test.mocks.dart 75:53          MockRSAKeysProvider.generate
  test/rsa_keys.test.dart 36:21                main.<fn>.<fn>
```

Comment: Your stub calls `RSA.generate`, so it depends on the actual implementation (which seems counterproductive).  Normally the stub should be returning a predetermined response.

Comment: so the problem is likely on the package itself rather than what I wrote?

Comment: I didn't say at all that it's a problem with the package.  Your test is inappropriate.

Comment: ah, I think I understood. As everytime I call generate() it gives me a different keyPair, even though the key size is the same, the stub method will fail because it expects to be the same return value each time I call it?

Comment: No, your stub method fails because it depends on `RSA.generate`, which requires that the test link in `librsa_bridge.dylib` via FFI.  It doesn't make sense for your stub method to call the actual `RSA.generate` implementation.

Comment: Also, your entire test isn't appropriate. The point of a `Mock` is to test how *other* code interacts with the mocked object. You cannot use a `MockRSAKeysProvider` to test the behavior of an `RSAKeysProvider` itself.

Comment: I see. Well, guess I was doing it all wrong. How could I test it though? When I try to do it "normally", it gives me the same error. By normally I mean:

```
test('Public and private key should not be null when generated', () async {
      final RSAKeysProvider rsaKeys = RSAKeysProvider();

      await rsaKeys.generate('2048');

      expect(rsaKeys.keyPair?.privateKey, isNotNull);
      expect(rsaKeys.keyPair?.publicKey, isNotNull);
    });
```

Comment: nevermind, the issue is in the package itself. A maintainer said that the package can't be executed in unit test, but they are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your stub calls `RSA.generate`, so it depends on the `RSA.generate` implementation which involves FFI and loading a dynamically-loaded library on whatever platform you run tests on.  Unless you're trying to test `package:fastrsa` itself, you should avoid calling things such as `RSA.generate` anyway; *that* is what you should be replacing with a stub.

The point of a `Mock` is to test how *other* code interacts with the mocked object. You cannot use a `MockRSAKeysProvider` to test the behavior of an `RSAKeysProvider` itself.  If you want to test the behavior of your `RSAKeysProvider` class, you could change it to accept a stub for `RSA.generate`:

```dart
class RSAKeysProvider {
  KeyPair? _keyPair;

  KeyPair? get keyPair => _keyPair;
  set setKeyPair(KeyPair keyPair) => _keyPair = keyPair;

  Future<void> generate(String bits, {Future<KeyPair> Function(int)? generate}) async {
    generate ??= RSA.generate;
    var keyPair = await generate(int.parse(bits));
    _keyPair = keyPair;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and then in your test:

```dart
Future<KeyPair> fakeGenerate(int bits) async {
  return KeyPair('fakePublicKey', 'fakePrivateKey'); // Or use precomputed values.
}

test('Public and private key should not be null when generated', () async {
  final RSAKeysProvider rsaKeys = RSAKeysProvider();
  await rsaKeys.generate('2048', generate: fakeGenerate);
  expect(rsaKeys.keyPair?.privateKey, isNotNull);
  expect(rsaKeys.keyPair?.publicKey, isNotNull);
});
```

Comment: I am confused. Why should I use a fakeGenerate function? Shouldn't I be testing with actual values?

Comment: @bringand1 1. Unless you're testing `package:fastrsa` itself, you probably can assume that it already works.  What *your* tests should be focusing on is the behavior of *your* `RSAKeysProvider` class. Unless `RSAKeysProvider`'s behavior is sensitive to the values of the generated keys, it shouldn't matter if the keys are fake. 2. If you don't like `KeyPair('fakePublicKey', 'fakePrivateKey')`, then generate a *real* `KeyPair` and make `fakeGenerate` hardcode those values.

Comment: oh, now I understood. Thanks! I had to make a correct in fakeGenerate, where instead of returning a KeyPair, I returned a Future.value(KeyPair), as only the KeyPair was not letting me compile. Other than that, it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mark `fakeGenerate` with `async`.  Corrected now.